# Install third-party C library on Mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos

I'd like to install a third-party C library (http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrs.html) on a Mac OS X. However, the binaries won't seem to install on a Mac OS X (10.9.5). The library is intended for Unix/Linux platforms.

Here are a couple example of errors I get when trying to install the `make` file. First, here's the error when running `make all` out of the box (for some reason, running `make all64` does nothing):

```
ld: library not found for -lgmp
```

I installed the GMP library (https://gmplib.org/) via MacPorts in `/opt/local`. However, the library does not appear to be found:

```
cc 2nash-GMP.o -L. -llrsgmp -L/opt/local/include  -lgmp -o 2nash
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [2nash] Error 1
rm 2nash-GMP.o
```

How can I get around all this and install on a Mac?

I'll mention that I intend to call a function from this C library many, many times within functions from some (Matlab) code I've written. I'd prefer any potential solution to allow for this.

**Update #1:**
I've since done the following:

- In the makefile, changed `LIBDIR` from `/usr/lib` to `/opt/local/lib`
- In the makefile, changed `INCLUDEDIR` from  `/usr/include` to `/opt/local/include`
- Copied `gmp.h` file from `/opt/local/include` to `/usr/include`
- In the makefile, changed `RANLIB ?= /bin/true` to `RANLIB ?= /usr/bin/true`

Now, when I run `make all`, I get the following message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

What other steps should be taken?

Comment: Just a note: I hope you're putting (compile time) .h files in /opt/local/include (and using -I compile switches), and (link time) .a/.so files in /opt/local/lib (using -L link switches).  I'd hate to see libraries in /any/place/include...

Answer (score 1):

I think you would, instead, want something like:

```
cc 2nash-GMP.o -L. -llrsgmp -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp -o 2nash
```

The `-I` option specifies a path to headers to include. The `-L` option specifies a path to library files to include.

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable `LIBDIR` in the makefile to the location where the libraries are installed, e.g.:

```
LIBDIR = /opt/local/lib
```